# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key randomNumber

Tags: swift, swift4, game-center

I have this function:

```
func processReceivedRandomNumber(randomNumberDetails: RandomNumberDetails) {
    // 1 
    let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: orderOfPlayers)
    mutableArray.add(randomNumberDetails)

    // 2
    let sortByRandomNumber = NSSortDescriptor(key: "randomNumber", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortByRandomNumber]
    mutableArray.sort(using: sortDescriptors)

    // 3
    orderOfPlayers = NSArray(array: mutableArray) as! [RandomNumberDetails]

    // 4
    if allRandomNumbersAreReceived() {
        receivedAllRandomNumbers = true
    }
}
```

I call it like:

```
processReceivedRandomNumber(randomNumberDetails: RandomNumberDetails(playerId: player, randomNumber: messageRandomNumber.randomNumber))
```

The Class used:

```
class RandomNumberDetails: NSObject {
    let playerId: String
    let randomNumber: UInt32

    init(playerId: String, randomNumber: UInt32) {
        self.playerId = playerId
        self.randomNumber = randomNumber
        super.init()
    }

      func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        let randomNumberDetails = object as? RandomNumberDetails
        return randomNumberDetails?.playerId == self.playerId
    }
}
```

I receive this error message:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key randomNumber.'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1850ff164 0x184348528 0x1850fee2c 0x185ab2434 0x1859f8e20 0x1859f8874 0x1859f861c 0x100f97d90 0x100f9a30c 0x100f9b4a8 0x100f91c3c 0x100f91d8c 0x19ee9baa0 0x19ee9bba8 0x19eea29e0 0x19e62ab1c 0x185afb2e4 0x1850a777c 0x1850a76fc 0x1850a6f84 0x1850a4b5c 0x184fc4c58 0x186e70f84 0x18e71d5c4 0x100f658d8 0x184ae456c)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray` with `NSSortDescriptor` in Swift? Use `Array` and `sort`.

Comment: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key randomNumber.'" => What is `RandomNumberDetails`?

Comment: @Larme Question edited

Comment: add `@objc` before the property `randomNumber`?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814783/valueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k)

Comment: @Larme thx bro , that's work : ) I just add `@objc before let randomNumber: UInt32 `